# Set background color table cell in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

i want to set the backgroundcolor of a couple of cells in codenameone
I was wondering if there is a function to do that
I kwow how to set the background color of a row in the table definition. But to set for each row a line.
But Is there something like setvalue? Like cell(row, column).getallstyles.bgcolor=

Answer (score 0):

Table cells are created dynamically based on model data so you need to override the cell creation method e.g.:

```java
Table table = new Table(model) {
    @Override
    protected Component createCell(Object value, int row, int column, boolean editable) { 
        Component cell = super.createCell(value, row, column, editable);
        
        if(!isValidValue(value)) { 
            cell.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0xff0000);
        }
        return cell;
    }
};
```

This sets all the cells with invalid values to red.

Comment: Thanx Shai, i was wondering. my table is static , i  change only the data of the cells of two columns.  how would i change the color of a cell in a static table when the color of the cell is not depending on the value of the cell but on another variabel. Like i have the data for one cell {2,5, 10, 1}  2 is row , 5 column , 10 the value and 1 is the flag to set the cell background red. How do i do that?

Comment: You can add a method to the model to determine the color then use something like `int color = ((MyModel)getModel()).getCellColor(row, rolumn);` then set that as the color... You can also use `setUIID` if there are a few pre-determined colors and separate the styling to the CSS

Comment: thanx Shai i dont know how i must put your answer in work. What i have to put in de defaulttablemodel for code. I solved now my question by adding in de defaultmodel for every color like this example code . But it would be easier to use something like this tabelmodel.setColor(row, column, color) when you want to change the color  the example code   if(row ==e && column == b) {  
       
            cell.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0x0000ff);
            cell.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
            cell.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0xFFFFFF, true);
        }

Comment: Inherit table model and add something like int[][] colors; Then make sure it's initialized to the right size with the right default values. Then add the getters/setters for an individual cell. When you write the method above just downcast to your default model subclass and invoke the right method.